# how to add close button to snack bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have a piece of code to generate the snack bar. I have used bootstrap alert with close option to generate the snack bar but when i click the close button is not working for me. Is it adding close option is possible? If yes, would you please explain how?

```js
function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
        x.className = "show";
        setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 10000);
    }
```

```css
#snackbar {
    visibility: hidden;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-left: -125px;
    background-color: #1E6C97;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 16px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    right:20px;
    bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#snackbar.show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2.5s, fadeout 3.5s 6.5s;
    animation: fadein 2.5s, fadeout 3.5s 6.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
    to {bottom: 40px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    to {bottom: 40px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 40px; opacity: 1;} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 40px; opacity: 1;}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar</button>
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable fade in" id="snackbar">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Join [12531] Buyers from [181] Countries Who Connect with Suppliers on PaperIndex
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could for example add onclick function to remove `.show` class from snackbar. See working example.

```
// jQuery    
onClick="$(this).parent().removeClass('show');"
// pure JS
onClick="this.parentNode.classList.remove('show');"
```

```js
function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
        x.className = "show";
        setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 1000000);
    }
```

```css
#snackbar {
    visibility: hidden;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-left: -125px;
    background-color: #1E6C97;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 16px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    right:20px;
    bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#snackbar.show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2.5s, fadeout 3.5s 6.5s;
    animation: fadein 2.5s, fadeout 3.5s 6.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
    to {bottom: 40px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    to {bottom: 40px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 40px; opacity: 1;} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 40px; opacity: 1;}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar</button>
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable fade in" id="snackbar">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" onClick="this.parentNode.classList.remove('show');">&times;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Join [12531] Buyers from [181] Countries Who Connect with Suppliers on PaperIndex
 </div>
```